Days elapsed since dates given, with time offset from multiple international dates
I have several dates/times that I need to display, in local time - but I'd also like to have the time elapsed in days/hours for each date:
2024-11-22 04:03:59 (4 days 17 hours ago)
The data I have from the json file I am working with is:
dateUpdated         | localTimeOffset
                    |
2024-11-21 12:05:32 | -05:00:00
2024-11-21 17:02:45 |  00:00:00
2024-11-22 04:03:59 |  11:00:00

These should all be around the same length of time ago, but obviously the local date/time doesn't make that obvious unless you factor in the offset; hence the request for time elapsed.
I am using vanilla JS.
Thanks in advance, if you require any further info please let me know.

Is this the raw data or has it been transformed in some way?  If you have the ISO8601 date time string you could do this pretty easily with Intl.DateFormat API. Also as an aside, due to many countries adopting some form of daylight savings time, the timezone offset number is likely going to be wrong for half the year.

What do you mean by elapsed? Between what and what? You need two points in time to talk about elapsed time. Do you mean the time between some past time record and the present time? But what time is present then? The time of running your JavaScript after loading a page? If you need the real “present”, you may need to handle a timing event and update the view as time passes, say, every second.

Another question: what exactly is stored in JSON? Local time records and the information of the time offset? Relative to what? Looks like a pretty bad idea. Can you change that? As soon as you work with multiple time zones, the best approach is working with UTC time, and only use local time when the time information is presented, say, on a Web page. With the other ways, you carry a lot of redundant data, to say the least.

By elapsed time, I mean time in days and hours since the stored date. I don't need any more precision than that - as such I'm not really that concerned by time changes due to DST. This is just a visual clue that something happened in the past, by roughly this amount of time.

is dateUpdated a local date/time value or an UTCz value ? + is localTimeOffset the local time specifically used to display the dateUpdated value or just a value to adjust the dateUpdated value to get an  UTCz value ?

The function formatDaysHours will format elapsed time in full days and full hours:


const formatDaysHours = elapsed => {
    const seconds = 1000;
    const minutes = seconds * 60;
    const hours = minutes * 60;
    const days = hours * 24;
    const elapsedDays = Math.floor(elapsed/days);
    const remainingTime = elapsed - elapsedDays * days;
    const elapsedHours = Math.floor(remainingTime/hours);
    const pluralDays = elapsedDays == 1 ? "" : "s";
    const pluralHours = elapsedHours == 1 ? "" : "s";
    return `${elapsedDays} day${pluralDays}, ${elapsedHours} hour${pluralHours}`;
};
    
// Usage example:
   
const startTime = new Date('November 23, 2024 23:55:55 GMT+10:00');
const endTime = new Date();
    
const elapsed = endTime - startTime; //milliseconds
console.log(formatDaysHours(elapsed));



If you need the nearest hour, you can replace Math.floor(remainingTime/hours) with Math.round(/* ... */). Note that multiplicity of nouns is taken into account: depending on the values, you can get “day” or “days”, “hour” or “hours”.
More importantly, look at my comments. Think of what is the end time of your intervals. If this is a really “present” time, you may want to handle timing events and update the view, say, every second. For hour accuracy, you would need a timing interval of about half an hour. Also, you should better store everything in UTC and present local time only locally in the UI.

Thanks, I'll have a play with this and see how it works in my UI.

@Tony Merryfield — If I miss something, please don't hesitate to comment and ask for assistance. Do you want to update the view using a timer event as time passes? If you want, will you cope with that? Please accept the answer formally as soon as the technique works for you.

I can handle the periodic updates to the view, but thanks for the offer. If I have any questions I'll let you know.

@Tony Merryfield — Perfect.

Works perfectly :) accepted the answer.

@Tony Merryfield — Thank you. Good luck!

Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving (DST) is observed, so elapsedDays  and elapsedHours will likely be wrong where the interval crosses a DST boundary. This answer also doesn't take into consideration the local offset, which is noted in the OP, nor does it make any attempt to correctly parse the OP timestamp format.

I presume that the timestamps in the OP are local values, with the offset to be deducted to get UTC. I.e.
2024-11-21 12:05:32 | -05:00:00

is
2024-11-21 17:05:32 UTC

Given the timestamp format, they'll need to be parsed manually. A library can help, but isn't necessary for single cases.


// Parse timestamp yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss, offset ±HH:mm:ss
// No offset is treated as +
function parseUTCwOffset(timestamp, offset) {
  // Parse timestamp
  let [yr, mon, day, hr, min, sec] = timestamp.split(/\D/);
  // Parse offset - subtract +ve, add -ve offsets
  let sign = offset.substring(0, 1) == '-' ? 1 : -1;
  let [oH, oM, oS] = offset.match(/\d+/g);
  // Create Date using UTC values
  return new Date(Date.UTC(yr, mon - 1, day, +hr + sign * oH, +min + sign * oM, +sec + sign * oS));
}

// Elapsed time difference in UTC, may be different to local where
// DST observed
// Returns an array of values: [sign(±), days, hours, mins, secs, millisecs]
function elapsedDiffUTC(d1, d2) {
  let diff = d2 - d1;
  let sign = diff < 0? '-' : '+';
  diff = Math.abs(diff);
  let days = diff/8.64e7 | 0; // Whole days
  let hrs  = diff % 8.64e7 / 3.6e6 | 0; // Whole hours
  let mins = diff % 3.60e6 / 6.0e4 | 0; // Whole minutes
  let secs = diff % 6.00e4 / 1.0e3 | 0; // Whole seconds
  return [sign, days, hrs, mins, secs];
}

// Example
[{
    dateUpdated: '2024-12-10 19:32:00',
    localTimeOffset: '10:00:00'
  },
  {
    dateUpdated: '2024-12-25 00:00:00', // Christmas day
    localTimeOffset: '-05:00:00'
  },
  {
    dateUpdated: '2024-11-21 12:05:32',
    localTimeOffset: '-05:00:00'
  },
  {
    dateUpdated: '2024-11-21 17:02:45',
    localTimeOffset: '+00:00:00'
  },
  {
    dateUpdated: '2024-12-22 04:03:59',
    localTimeOffset: '+11:00:00'
  }
].forEach(({dateUpdated, localTimeOffset}) => {
  let date = parseUTCwOffset(dateUpdated, localTimeOffset);
  let [sign, day, hr, min, sec] = elapsedDiffUTC(Date.now(), date);
  // Initial values + equivalent UTC timestamp
  console.log(dateUpdated + ' | ' + localTimeOffset + '\n' + date.toISOString());
  // Elapsed time, exclude zero values
  let elapsedString = sign + (day == 0? '' : day + 'days, ') +
                             (hr == 0? '' : hr + 'hr, ') +
                             (min == 0? '' : min + 'min, ') +
                             (sec == 0? '' : sec + 'sec, ');
                             
  console.log(elapsedString);
});



